# Is there a way to get recursive mocks on a class return value with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

NSubstitute says this in its [docs](http://nsubstitute.github.com/help/auto-and-recursive-mocks/):

> methods that return an interface [...] will automatically return substitutes themselves.

That is enough usually.  However, when I do this:

TestMethod:

```
IUnityContainer unity = Substitute.For<IUnityContainer>();
MyMethod(unity);
```

Actual Method:

```
    public void MyMethod(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;

        myObject = container.Resolve<ISomeObject>();

        myObject.CallSomeMethod();
    }
```

The Resolve Method returns a class.  So it is not mocked.  That means I get null in myObject and a null reference exception when I call `CallSomeMethod`;

It would be nice if I could just get a class returned that is a mock (that is unless I have overridden that interface specifically).

Is there any way to get this using **NSubstitute**?

Comment: Won't `IUnityContainer.Resolve<T>` return a `T`? So if `T` is an interface `ISomeObject`, NSubstitute should return an mocked `ISomeObject` if you call `container.Resolve<ISomeObject>()`. It's not doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ISomeObject` is an interface this should work fine. If you want to get auto-substitute classes, the class needs to have a default constructor, and have all it's public members declared as virtual.

The following tests pass for me:

```
public interface IFactory { T Resolve<T>(); }
public interface ISomeObject { void CallSomeMethod(); }

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Example()
    {
        var factory = Substitute.For<IFactory>();
        MyMethod(factory);
    }
    public void MyMethod(IFactory container)
    {
        var myObject = container.Resolve<ISomeObject>();
        myObject.CallSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out IUnityContainer.Resolve<T>() is an extension method.  I am guessing NSubstitute does not do anything for extension methods...

Comment: Ah, nicely found. Yes, NSub won't intercept ext/static methods. I would suggest not marking this answer as correct, as the real answer is the one you found: it won't work on static/extension methods.